# This photo {has been taken vs. was taken} in Okinawa

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

A. This photo has been taken in Okinawa

B. This photo was taken in Okinawa

Which one would be correct? In the case that if I don't want to specify a date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are correct, but Version B is probably the one you want to say.

Version A might be preferred as a lead-in statement in certain contexts. For example, if I was showing you a picture of a famous building or vista in Okinawa, I might say something like:

> *This photo has been taken in Okinawa hundreds of times*.

(meaning, not that exact photo, but many photos very similar to it).

Answer (score 1):

"It was" is the correct past tense form, indicating an action that takes place completely in the past.

To contrast, "it has been" is a *present perfect* tense, indicating something that began in the past but continues now.